# Location of imported 3D models

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, models, mesh

So whenever I load a 3D model (.3ds, .obj, etc) into my openGL program, they either get placed in a seemingly random location or they're oriented in a not-ideal position. Is there an easy way to make it so that when I import a model it goes to a location I specify? I'm thinking this could be handled using a vertex shader and translating the input location by some vector addition but this would require knowing where it was going to appear in the first place in order to know how much to translate it by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to figure out what the "correct orientation" is. When you see a teapot, should its handle be on the left or the right?

However, the correct location can be slightly easier to adjust.

Let's assume you would like your loaded object to show up at (Lx, Ly, Lz)

First, compute the centroid of the vertices (Cx, Cy, Cz) by adding each coordinate and averaging it. Eg: For the 3 points (1,0,1), (0,1,1) and (0,0,1), the centroid is (1/3, 1/3, 1).

Now offset every vertex by (Lx-Cx, Ly-Cy, Lz-Cz), and your geometry should be "centered" around the location (Lx, Ly, Lz).

Note: This works well for fairly symmetrical models (eg: people, creatures, cars, etc.).

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

That entirely depends on the transformations applied to your 3D model, or the coordinate system used in your 3D modelling package. I'd say you're approaching this from the wrong end. If you want your data to be consistent, make sure it's exported in a manner you expect from your 3D modelling package.

Comment: Since I'm getting most of my models from sites like turbosquid or google 3D warehouse I'm not sure if it's possible to check coordinate system used by a particular model.

Comment: I don't know if the site has any indication of this or if you can deduce it from the package it was created in. But if not, I would simply take the model into your favourite package and correct it there. I wouldn't want to take the route of trying to deduce an orientation/translation and then automatigically correcting it. Let your input be consistent.